# Laravel custom composer libaray class not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package-managers

I've created my custom php library with composer. The `composer.json` of this library looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "singboard/platform-fetcher",
    "description": "Fetch reviews from third part platforms.",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "version": "0.1.0-dev",
    "authors": [
       [...]
    ],
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        [...]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        [...]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Singboard\\PlatformFetcher\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

The folder structure of the composer library is this:

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── src
    └── FacebookFetcher.php
```

Now I've included this library to my laravel project. In the `composer.json` for my laravel project I've added this:

```
 "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "singboard/platform-fetcher",
                "version": "0.1.0-dev",
                "type": "library",
                "source": {
                    "url": "xxx-xxx",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],

"require": {
        "singboard/platform-fetcher": "0.1.0-dev"
    },
```

The problem is that when I try to call the `FacebookFetcher.php` class I get the message `Class 'Singboard\PlatformFetcher\FacebookFetcher' not found`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As reported in the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) this is not the correct way to include a custom remote library. You should implement your library with:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```